# DQL Request Error

Tags: symfony, dql

I tried to get the number of comments  using dql in this Action:

But i have this error:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 110: Error: Expected end of string, got '.'
```

[image]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please paste this code directly in the question rather than a link to it.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with your parameter declaration in query:
`p.id = :c.project_id` - Parameter must not contain a dot (`.`) it it's name.

But it seems You're trying to JOIN `CommentaireProject` with `Project` - please read more on how to JOIN property in [doctrine docs](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#joins).